# Gerando link em loop

Tags: php

Eu quero gerar links com os resultados de uma busca em banco de dados. Como fazer isso? Neste caso, quero gerar o link no resultado $numped.

```
//loop
while($linha=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    //pegando o dado dos campos...                
    $numped = $linha["numped"];
    $data = $linha["data"];
    $vencto = $linha["vencto"];
    $status = $linha["desc_status"];

    //montando a table...
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' .  $numped . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .  $data . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .  $vencto . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .  $status . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}
```

Comment: Mostre o que já tentou fazer

Comment: O $numped é um link? Mostra um exemplo do que ele retorna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que tipo de valor e retornado com $numped ??

se quiser que o $numped seja um link basta fazer assim

```
echo '<td><a href"#">' .  $numped . '</a></td>';
```

substituindo o # pelo URI do link q deseja, se o proprio $numped for o link faça assim

```
echo '<td><a href"'.$numped.'">' .  $numped . '</a></td>';
```

poste mais detalhes para melhor poder te ajudar.